# Unknown type name in CGo Linux to Windows cross compilation

Tags: windows, go, winapi, cross-compiling, cgo

I'm trying out some Windows API functions using CGO. I have a dockerfile which builds the binary using the command. I am cross compiling for Windows from Linux

```bash
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig;

    GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 \
        CGO_CFLAGS="-isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include \
        -I /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/gst-include/glib-2.0 \
        -I/usr/share/mingw-w64/include -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/gst-include/gstreamer-1.0" \
        CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig -Luser32" \
        CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ \
        CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build -o bin/yaoe.exe main.go
```

I'm trying to compile the following code with CGO

windows_helpers.h

```c
#ifndef WINHELPERS_H
#define WINHELPERS_H

#include <windows.h>

LPCSTR wrapMAKEINTRESOURCEA(UINT_PTR i);
void CQueryDisplayConfig();

#endif // WINHELPERS_H
```

windows_helpers.c

```c
#include "winhelpers_windows.h"

// wrapMAKEINTRESOURCEA wraps the MAKEINTRESOURCEA macro in a callable function
LPCSTR wrapMAKEINTRESOURCEA(UINT_PTR i) {
    return MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i);
}

void CQueryDisplayConfig() {
    UINT32 flags = 0x00000001;
    UINT32 numPathArrayElements;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO *pathArray;
    UINT32 numModeInfoArrayElements;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO *modeInfoArray;
    DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID *currentTopologyId;

    LONG queryReturn = QueryDisplayConfig(flags, &numPathArrayElements,
                                          &pathArray, &numModeInfoArrayElements,
                                          &modeInfoArray, &currentTopologyId);
}
```

And this is how I include it in my .go file

```golang
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I . -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L . -luser32 -l/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
#include "winhelpers_windows.h"
*/
import "C"
```

I get the following error

```bash
winhelpers_windows.c: In function 'CQueryDisplayConfig':
winhelpers_windows.c:11:5: error: unknown type name 'DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO'
   11 |     DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO *pathArray;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
winhelpers_windows.c:13:5: error: unknown type name 'DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO'
   13 |     DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO *modeInfoArray;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
winhelpers_windows.c:14:5: error: unknown type name 'DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID'
   14 |     DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID *currentTopologyId;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
winhelpers_windows.c:16:24: warning: implicit declaration of function 'QueryDisplayConfig'; did you mean 'CQueryDisplayConfig'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   16 |     LONG queryReturn = QueryDisplayConfig(flags, &numPathArrayElements,
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        CQueryDisplayConfig
```

I have checked inside `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include` and the typedefs do actually exist

```bash
yaoe@2a0b8c6ab378:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include$ grep -Rn DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID
wingdi.h:2255:  } DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID;
winuser.h:5621:  WINUSERAPI LONG WINAPI QueryDisplayConfig (UINT32 flags, UINT32 *numPathArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO *pathArray, UINT32 *numModeInfoArrayElements, DISPLAYCO
NFIG_MODE_INFO *modeInfoArray, DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID *currentTopologyId);

--------------------

yaoe@2a0b8c6ab378:/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include$ grep -Rn DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO
wingdi.h:2238:  typedef struct DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO {
wingdi.h:2242:  } DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO;
winuser.h:5620:  WINUSERAPI LONG WINAPI SetDisplayConfig (UINT32 numPathArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO *pathArray, UINT32 numModeInfoArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO *mo
deInfoArray, UINT32 flags);
winuser.h:5621:  WINUSERAPI LONG WINAPI QueryDisplayConfig (UINT32 flags, UINT32 *numPathArrayElements, DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO *pathArray, UINT32 *numModeInfoArrayElements, DISPLAYCO
NFIG_MODE_INFO *modeInfoArray, DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID *currentTopologyId);
```

The typedefs are inside `wingdi.h` which is being included by `windows.h`

Not quite sure what is going wrong. Microsoft docs say simply including `windows.h` should be enough, and sure enough every other header that contains these typedefs are included inside `windows.h`

Comment: Works for me on `linux/amd64` (Debian 12) with Go 1.21.1 (and 1.17.x) and `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32` 12.2.0-14+25.2 using the call `GOOS=windows CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-win32`

Comment: (I was required to make a couple of obvious tweaks to make the C code compile, and I've also removed the unneeded `-L/usr/...` and `-I/usr/...` bits but otherwise no changes.) I would double check (run `set`) you do not have any funny exported variables which could affect the compilation. Also make sure it's not called by some build system which could do the same.

Comment: Also maybe–just maybe–you've been calling `go build` while properly setting `GOOS` but not `CC` which made stock `gcc` being used which would not be able to properly process `windows.h` et all. This might also explain why you've explicitly added pathnames of MinGW stuff to your compiler and linker flags.

Comment: Checked all environment vars that are set and I do not see any glaring issues. I figured the issue was to do with `wingdi.h` so I also linked with `gdi32` but that didn't work either. Don't think the build command is the issue as I've got some other Win32 API calls in C, and they are actually working fine. This is one that I have `LPCSTR wrapMAKEINTRESOURCEA(UINT_PTR i) {
    return MAKEINTRESOURCEA(i);
}
`

Comment: The `wrapMAKEINTRESOURCEA` function also includes `windows.h` albeit `MAKEINTRESOURCEA` is inside `winuser.h`. Also, the imports are "ifdef guarded" so I don't believe anything's being imported twice

One thing I've done is I've copy pasted a bunch of gstreamer mingw windows headers inside my dockerfile as I couldn't find said headers via `apt`, that's about the only change in the Dockerfile

Comment: [`QueryDisplayConfig()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) was introduced in Windows 7. You'll have to let your compiler know that that is your minimum target. [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers) explains which values to assign to the respective preprocessor symbols that control the target.

Comment: @IInspectable, I think you've nailed it: in the package `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32` 12.2.0-14+25.2 I have on my system, `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` are both defined to be 0x0a00 by default (Win10). Explicitly setting them to 0x0500 by sticking `-DWINVER=0x0500 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0500` into `CFLAGS` make the compilation fail in exactly the way stated in the question. So looks like one way is to explicitly bump the versions using something like `-DWINVER=0x0a00 ...` or arrange for a fresher MinGW to be installed.

Comment: Relying on build environment defaults is an expensive decision. You'll be sinking hours, days, and weeks into diagnosing why your binaries started behaving oddly. Be explicit in what you ask for. This is especially true for build scripts or CI infrastructure in general.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Resolved after defining proper macros

Comment: @IInspectable, care to post your 1st commend in this thread as an answer? ;-)

Comment: Riptide is in a far better position to post an answer. They know how to solve the issue and have verified that the solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IInspectable mentioned, the error had to do with `SetDisplayConfig` and `QueryDisplayConfig` being introduced in Windows 7, and since I had not provided any compilation target, MinGW failed to find the function definitions.

Explicitly telling the compiler to compile for Windows 10 and above fixed the issue

```c
// Compile for windows 10 and above
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN10 0x0A00
#define WINVER 0x0A00
```